# JavaFX: Binding expression in FXML document

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

In JavaFX 8 is it still possible to bind a control property directly in FXML to a property of the controller?
Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   fx:controller="application.PaneController" minWidth="200">
   <Label id="counterLabel" text="${controller.counter}" />
   <Button translateX="50" text="Subtract 1"
      onAction="#handleStartButtonAction" />
</GridPane>
```

The above seems not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible assuming you implement the correct methods in the controller:

```
public class PaneController {

    private final IntegerProperty counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(100);

    public IntegerProperty counterProperty() {
        return counter;
    }

    // this is also required
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }

    public void handleStartButtonAction() {
        counter.set(counter.get() - 1);
    }

}
```

Also I'm not sure if placing both `Node`s in the same cell is the best decision...

Comment: I have only implemeted the couterProperty getter but not the plain one.
Okay this works. Thank you

Comment: With e(fx)clipse plugin you can generate this getter/setter/property by : right-clic/source/generate JavaFX Getters and Setters